# Emacs package versions

Tags: emacs, elisp, bbdb

After installing Emacs BBDB  from [Melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net) on GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) for Windows, if I run `M-x bbdb-version` I get:

```
 BBDB version @PACKAGE_VERSION@ (@PACKAGE_DATE@)
```

How can I know if I am using the new version 3 of BBDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, the author uses a build system to define and replace these names with their correct values, but melpa does not support making changes to the upsteam repo.

The truth is, if you just downloaded it from melpa, then it is safe to say you are running version > 3. If you really want to be sure, do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>bbdb-with-print-loadably</kbd> and see if that function is defined, it was added to bbdb in one of the most recent commits to the git repo and well past the last release commit of version 3.1.2.

See also: https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa/issues/1470

Comment: yes, I have `bbdb-with-print-loadably`. Are there alternatives to melpa working under M$ Windows and not showing the bug?

Comment: Maybe check marmalade but i doubt it would be different, or if you want, you could always get the source and build it.